# how to make a text data from json show directly in a page?

Tags: json, android-studio, flutter, dart

I have been trying to make the data from a json show directly inside a page like one paragraph, but I failed to do so, I succeeded pulling it with a button but I just want the data to show after I enter this page directly.
what I have been missing here?
thank you a lot for your help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return Page1State();
  }

  Future<List> getData() async {
    String myURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
    http.Response response = await http.get(myURL);
    print(getData());
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
}

class Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  var page = Page1();
  List data;
  List myTextData;


   void getMyData() async {
    data = await (page.getData());
    print(data);
    setState(() {
      myTextData = data;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page1'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Text(
                  '$getMyData',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Home.dart';

main() async {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Home(),
    title: '',
  ));
}
```

Comment: because `getMyData` is a void method, that's why you won't get anything

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
List<MyModel> mList=List();
```

then update myTextData from api response,

```
 void getMyData() async {
    data = await (page.getData());
    print(data);
    setState(() {
      mList.addAll(data);
    });
  }
```

```
ListView.builder
  (
    itemCount: mList.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
     return new Text(mList[index]);
    }
  )
```

Comment: it gives me null, that is the problem that I had in the first place.

Comment: and I had to keep List myTextData instead of String.

Comment: it gives me NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.

Comment: Check my updated answer! I forgot to initialize the List();

Answer (score 0):

1. keep the getdata method in your state
2. Don't do json.decode as you are displaying as string

Try this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
        return Page1State();
      }
    }
 @override
  void initState() { 
    super.initState();
    getMyData();
  }

class Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  String data;   

  void getMyData() async {
    String myURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
    http.Response response = await http.get(myURL);
    setState((){
      data = response.body; //do not decode as you want to show as  string
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page1'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                child: data == null ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Text(
                  '$data',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the CircularProgressIndicator keep looping in this case, and the async library was not used, is that normal?

Comment: sorry my bad, the async is no longer needed and i forgot to gall getmydata, we should do that in initstate, have made the modifications. please check

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `FutureBuilder` which will allow you to make your Widget stateless. Snapshot in FututeBuilder's `builder` also has couple useful fields like `connectionState` which will let you easily implement all the states (waiting, done, errored).

More about it here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Since your output is a JSON I also included a example how to simple extract data from it.

```
class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<List> getData() async {
    String myURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
    http.Response response = await http.get(myURL);
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page1'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                child: new SingleChildScrollView(
              child: FutureBuilder<List>(
                  future: getData(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Text(
                        snapshot.data
                            .map((user) => user['name'] as String)
                            .join('\n'),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Text('Waiting');
                    }
                  }),
            )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```